# Hi I'm getting error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Hi I have created a simple app that uses three apis to fetch data and render that data appropriately in the webpage. It uses node, express server, body-parser and cors, as middleware. Also I compiled all the code in webpack and ran the webpack dev-server in which the error is appearing. Here is my server.js:

```
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
cityData = {};
weatherData = {};
picturesData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();

/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
app.use(cors())
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('../website/client'));

app.get("/all", function sendData(req, res) {
    res.send(cityData);
})

app.get("/allWeather", function sendWeather(req, res) {
    res.send(weatherData);
})

app.get("/allPictures", function sendPictures(req, res) {
    res.send(picturesData);
})


app.post("/addWeather", (req, res) => {
    weatherData['temp'] = req.body.temp;
    res.send(weatherData);
})

app.post("/addPicture", (req, res) => {
    picturesData['pic'] = req.body.pic;
    res.send(picturesData);
})

// Setup Server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("App listening on port 3000")
    console.log("Go to http://localhost:3000")
})
```

Here is my app.js:

```
const geoURL = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?";
const geoUsername = `rohanasif1990`;
const weatherURL = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?"
const weatherKey = "20028a8267a24bba9a807362767bc4a7"
const pixabayKey = "30776478-ff0b8818f9bba72161ebb1731"
const pixabayURL = "https://pixabay.com/api?"

const present = new Date();

const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    const departure = document.getElementById("date").value;
    const [depart_date, depart_time] = departure.split("T")
    const [depart_year, depart_month, depart_day] = depart_date.split("-")
    const [depart_hour, depart_minute] = depart_time.split(":")

    const future = new Date(depart_year, depart_month - 1, depart_day, depart_hour, depart_minute);

    console.log(future);
    console.log(present);
    if (city !== "" || departTime !== "") {

        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = `Departure in ${(future - present) / 3600000 / 24} days`
        getCity(geoURL, city, geoUsername)
            .then(function (data) {
                return getWeather(weatherURL, weatherKey, data["geonames"][0]['lat'], data["geonames"][0]['lng'])
            }).then(weatherData => {
                return postWeatherData("/addWeather", { temp: weatherData['data'][0]['temp'] })
            }).then(function () {
                return receiveWeatherData()
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Please enter a valid city and a valid time");
            })
        getPictures(city, pixabayURL, pixabayKey)
            .then(function (picsData) {
                return postPictureData("/addPicture", { pic: picsData['hits'][0]["webformatURL"] })
            })
            .then(function () {
                return receivePictureData()
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("No pictures found")
            })
    }
})

const getCity = async (geoURL, city, geoUsername) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${geoURL}q=${city}&username=${geoUsername}`);
    try {
        const cityData = await res.json();
        return cityData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}


const postWeatherData = async (url = "", data = {}) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            temp: data.temp
        })
    });

    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        return newData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const receiveWeatherData = async () => {
    const request = await fetch("/allWeather");
    try {
        const allData = await request.json()
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "TEMPERATURE: " + allData['temp'];
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
    }
}

const getWeather = async (weatherURL, weatherKey, lat, lon) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${weatherURL}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&key=${weatherKey}`);
    try {
        const weatherData = await res.json();
        return weatherData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}

const getPictures = async (city, pixabayURL, pixabayKey) => {
    const query = city.split(" ").join("+");
    const res = await fetch(`${pixabayURL}key=${pixabayKey}&q=${query}`);
    try {
        const picsData = await res.json();
        return picsData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
    }
}

const receivePictureData = async () => {
    const request = await fetch("/allPictures");
    try {
        const allData = await request.json()
        document.getElementById("city-pic").src = allData['pic'];
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
    }
}

const postPictureData = async (url = "", data = {}) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            pic: data.pic
        })
    });

    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        return newData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

To see the error I ran "npm i" to install dependencies and webpack packages. Then "npm run build-prod" to build the project dist folder. Then running "npm run build-dev". Then in incognito go to localhost:3000. And when I enter some city name like "london". I get the following errors:

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbgXm.png)

I can't figure out why there are errors at lines 130 and 64. I'm new to javascript and have been doing many web development projects but never seen this kind of error. It seems like the data being sent or received is not JSON which it should be but rather an HTML file. I think the server is serving only the static HTML file and executing none of the code in app.js. Please have a look and please help me solve this issue as this is an important project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

That is an error page came in response instead of the JSON.

Comment: yes I know... previously the app was working flawlessly.. it was fetching data and displaying it properly.... I have been committing the project on github regularly and have lost track on when it was last working.

Comment: Looks like the API is not working. If you can see the response in postman like tool or save the full response as html file and see the error details in there will give you an idea of what is wrong with APIs.

Comment: I checked on postman and all three api's are fetching data correctly... don't know why my app is not doing the same

Comment: So after banging my head against the wall for hours I've come to the conclusion that the issue is with "postWeatherData" and "postPictureData" . I console.logged the data received from the functions and its a 404 not found issue...now on to solving this!...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (I am starting on webdev/django). Problem was that one object inside the model I was trying to serialize was not serializable. Maybe take a look on that.